# Как декодировать строку "Dsadd\\xc3\\xa1" в 'utf_8'?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, decode

если создать строку без экранирования(\) символа "\"
то вроде получается желаемый результат

```
v = "Dsadd\xc3\xa1
print(v) #  DsaddÃ
```

по этому я подумал просто удалить из строки эти штрихи "\"
c помощью регулярных выражения

```
re.sub(r'',"", v , flags=re.MULTILINE)# Dsadd\xc3\xa1
```

казалось бы теперь можно перевести все в bytes и прогнать через v.decode('utf_8'), но v.encoding('utf_8') и bytes(v) переводит просто экранируя "\"

```
b'Dsadd\\xc3\\xa1'
```

хотелось бы получить что то вроде

```
v = "Dsadd\\xc3\\xa1" # str

v.decode('utf_8') # DsaddÃ
```

Comment: [вот похожый вопрос с stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311277/evaluate-utf-8-literal-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python3/26311382#26311382)

Answer (score 1):

```
v = v.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
v.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

Все дело в latin1 который не экранируюет "\" :D